How to keep workspace structure when external main screen is disconnected
I'm using a laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 and gnome.
I use an external monitor at my office and choose it as my main screen, with my laptop monitor closed.
I create multiple workspaces on the main screen. When I disconnect the external monitor all but one workspaces will disappear, leaving all windows in one workspace on my laptop screen.
Is there any way to hold the structure of workspaces when the main screen is disconnected?

Alright, I find it something to do with the multi-monitor workspace setting. I just run
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter workspaces-only-on-primary false

to enable workspace not only on primary screen and the structure holds.
